# Golang pprof full call graph

Tags: go, pprof

I'm kinda new to `pprof`. I've started CPU profiling, and after a bit of time checked the top25. This is what I got:

```
Showing top 25 nodes out of 174
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  1.01mins 21.92% 21.92%   1.10mins 23.83%  time.Time.AppendFormat
  0.26mins  5.56% 27.48%   0.26mins  5.56%  type..eq.[65]runtime.sigTabT
  0.23mins  5.07% 32.55%   0.23mins  5.07%  type..hash.[3]runtime.symbol_key
  0.15mins  3.14% 35.69%   0.15mins  3.14%  type..hash.[9]string
  ...
```

I thought that's all cool, I just need to get rid of that time function. Then realized, I don't even use anything from the time pkg, so it must be either a third party lib, or one of the go internal functions.

So I've generated the graph with the `-web` flag, so I can see which function calls it, but it doesn't really show directly. Is there any way to track it down where it's coming from?

Comment: currently, all external tools using entire pprof possibilities, so I thing you can find everything inside pprof docs

Comment: what's the type of the generated image? ( e.g. -inuse_space      Display in-use memory size
  -inuse_objects    Display in-use object counts
  -alloc_space      Display allocated memory size
  -alloc_objects    Display allocated object counts)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the following approach to see everything.

`go tool pprof -http :9999 -edgefraction 0 -nodefraction 0 -nodecount 100000 cpu.prof`

This can give you a huge graph which can be quite difficult to follow. To help with that you can click on the offending node in the web view and select 'Focus' from the 'Refine' menu in the top left corner. This provides a view of that node and all its callers and callees.

The key options to use in order to see everything are:

```
--nodecount=<n>    Show at most so many nodes [default=80]
--nodefraction=<f> Hide nodes below <f>*total [default=.005]
--edgefraction=<f> Hide edges below <f>*total [default=.001]
```

You can also use `-focus` on the command line to speed up rendering of large graphs.

```
--focus=<regexp> Focus on nodes matching <regexp>
```